# Pegar o ID dos elementos ao arrastar e soltar

Tags: jquery-ui

Achei este código na internet e estou estudando como ele funciona, para tentar adaptar em um sistema, já consegui pegar o `id` do elemento pai, o `id` do LI que cliquei não esta vindo certo, e preciso que me mostre o elemento para onde ele foi arrastado.

Resumindo, ele deve me mostrar no `alert` o `id` da caixa principal, o `id` clicado, e o `id` da caixa que soltei.

http://fxcomp.com.br/teste.html

```
<script>
$(function () {
        $("#items1,#items2,#items3").sortable({
                connectWith: "#items1,#items2,#items3",
                start: function (event, ui) {

                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {

                            var id_principal = $(this).attr('id');
                            var id_do_li = $('li').attr('id');
                            alert('Id Pricipal = '+id_principal+' | Id do li = '+id_do_li);

                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                }
        });

        $("#items1,#items2,#items3").disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta colocando o código que você já tem e que está com erro?

Comment: Editei Eduardo, na verdade não esta dando erro, não consigo pegar os id clicados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitua o evento `stop` por `receive`, veja todas as propriedades [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/fzsrq2a9/1/).

O objeto `ui` retornado a partir do evento contém as seguintes propriedades:

- `item`: atual elemento arrastado.
- `sender`: elemento de origem.

E para capturar o elemento de destino utilize o `$(this)`:

```
$(".items").sortable({
    connectWith: ".items",
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        var id_origem = ui.sender.attr("id"),
            id_clicado = ui.item.attr("id"),
            id_destino = $(this).attr("id");
    }
});
```

Veja exemplo funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzsrq2a9/1/).

Comment: Obrigado Lucio, exatamente o que estava precisando!!

Comment: Valeu @MarcosPaulo. Por favor, aceita esta resposta para que outros usuários possam utilizar este post futuramente, obrigado!

Comment: Lúcio Rubens, testando este codigo no celular, ele não funciona, sera que tem alguma forma de modificar ele para mobile?

Comment: Pode deixar, era so pesquisar um pouco, colocando este JS resolve 

jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o *id* do item que foi arrastado você vai ter que usar o `ui` que é passado no *stop*

```
$(function () {
        $("#items1,#items2,#items3").sortable({
                connectWith: "#items1,#items2,#items3",
                start: function (event, ui) {

                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
                },
                stop: function (event, ui) {

                            var id_principal = $(this).attr('id');
                            var id_do_li = $('li').attr('id');
                            var teste = ui.item.attr("id");
                            alert('Id Pricipal = '+id_principal+' | Id do li = '+id_do_li+' | Id divi Final = '+teste);


                        ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");

                }
        });



        $("#items1,#items2,#items3").disableSelection();
});
```

O *stop* me mostra todas as propriedades do item que está sendo arrastado, assim eu posso pegar as propriedades deste item da mesma forma que pego qualquer outro objeto *jQuery*. O código que faz isso é

```
var teste = ui.item.attr("id");
```

Você pode ver um exemplo funcionando aqui:

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpyLq32q/1/)

Comment: Valeu Erlon, obrigado, agora como consigo pegar o ID do ul que ele foi solto?

Agora tenho o UL inicial, o LI arrastado, so falta o UL de destino